# Xamarin forms Convert Json Array to C# and back to JSON array

Tags: javascript, c#, json, visual-studio, xamarin

I have been trying to post a c# into an Api post that accepts a JSON array.

I think I am losing my mind trying to find solutions to these problems.

this i the sample json

```
Array
(
    [user_id] => 0002323445635
    [order] => {"order":{"cart_items":[{"id":"23","quantity":"2","price":350,"type":"Wash and Iron","name":"Gown"},{"id":"23","quantity":"1","price":200,"type":"Iron only","name":"Gown"}],"order_details":{"pickup_address":"trans ","telephone":"08063305699","pickup_date":"18\/3\/2020","pickup_time":"1.00PM - 3.00PM","delivery_date":"5\/3\/2020","delivery_time":"7.00AM - 9.00AM","total_price":"550","total_quantity":"2"}}}
)
```

But I am used to the normal list serialization. Json2Cshap and the rest says invalid JSON.

Comment: Well your sample "json" is invalid. Have a look at https://json.org what makes a valid json

Comment: You  use `JsonDeserialize` to convert response in model . Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60165218/how-to-deserializing-json-object-array-with-xamarin-forms .

Answer (score 0):

try this with your json

```
json = json.Replace("\","");
```

Comment: json = json.Replace("\\",""); I came back and found this useful thanks